# R: Plot multiple functions with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I need to plot multiple explicit functions definitions to compare them visually.

Consider the family of functions:

```
fun.1 <- function(x) { 1 / ( 0.01 + x) }
fun.2 <- function(x) { 1 / ( 0.1 + x) }
fun.3 <- function(x) { 1 / ( 0.3 + x) }
```

The idea is to plot the result of evaluating these functions
on the following inputs:

```
xs = c(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048)
```

Currently, my code is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

xs = c(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048)

fun.1 <- function(x) { 1 / ( 0.01 + x) }
fun.2 <- function(x) { 1 / ( 0.1 + x) }
fun.3 <- function(x) { 1 / ( 0.3 + x) }

base <- ggplot(data.frame(x = xs), aes(x=as.factor(x)))

base + theme_classic() +
       theme(
          legend.position = c(.95, .95),
          legend.justification = c("right", "top"),
          legend.box.just = "right",
          legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6)
          ) +
       geom_function(fun = fun.1, colour = "red") + 
       geom_function(fun = fun.2, colour = "blue") +
       geom_function(fun = fun.3, colour = "yellow") +
       scale_x_discrete(name = "Input",
                        breaks = xs) +
       scale_y_discrete(name = "Growth")
```

[The resulting plot is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYTSU.png)

Now this looks ugly among other things, i can't make the legend to appear and there are warnings:

```
Multiple drawing groups in `geom_function()`. Did you use the correct `group`, `colour`, or `fill` aesthetics?
Multiple drawing groups in `geom_function()`. Did you use the correct `group`, `colour`, or `fill` aesthetics?
Multiple drawing groups in `geom_function()`. Did you use the correct `group`, `colour`, or `fill` aesthetics?
```

The style i'm trying to get is like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDfXq.png). Ideally, the points should be visible
and connected by a continuous curve.

The question is, what is the best way to create a plot with multiple functions with a style like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDfXq.png) ?

Comment: This would be entirely a styling issue, maybe this resource would help you choose the best style? http://zevross.com/blog/2014/08/04/beautiful-plotting-in-r-a-ggplot2-cheatsheet-3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just `lapply()` over something and if it automatically gets added to the ggplot because it is a list. This is only useful though if the output of the lapply loop are things ggplot understands, such as geoms.

The example below assumes that the relevant function can be found using the naming structure you provided.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

xs = c(1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048)

fun.1 <- function(x) { 1 / ( 0.01 + x) }
fun.2 <- function(x) { 1 / ( 0.1 + x) }
fun.3 <- function(x) { 1 / ( 0.3 + x) }

ggplot(data.frame(x = xs), aes(x=x)) + 
  lapply(1:3, function(i) {
    fun_name <- paste0("fun.", i)
    fun <- get(fun_name)
    line <- geom_function(fun = fun,
                          aes(colour = fun_name))
    points <- geom_point(aes(y = fun(xs), colour = fun_name))
    list(line, points)
  }) +
  scale_x_log10(breaks = xs, name = "Input") +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Growth") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(.95, .95),
    legend.justification = c("right", "top"),
    legend.box.just = "right",
    legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6)
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Point of note, whereas your plot seems continuous in almost every way, you add the `_discrete()` variant of position scales which I don't understand. I converted everything to numeric instead.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know something like lapply() could be possible. Is it possible for the round points to be different not just by color, but also on "form"?, i mean like: round, star, square, triangle, etc. In this way the plot can also be printed in black and white.

Comment: BTW, the `_discrete()` thing is because i couldn't make the ticks appear at the same distance, so i started to experiment. It seems you solved that by using `_log10`.

Comment: However, i think the shape of the curve can be badly affected with `_log10`.

Comment: Sure you can add `shape = fun_name` inside the `aes()` of the `geom_point()`. I don't know what exactly you mean with 'badly affected'. In what way? Note that if you use `as.factor(xs)`, the x-position under the hood is converted to `1:length(xs)` since factors are integers with a `levels` attribute. Which seems more harmful than log-transforming the axis.

Comment: Maybe it is not that apparent in the function of my code. To see what i mean, consider this similar variation: function(x) { 1 / ( 0.01 + (0.99/x)), function(x) { 1 / ( 0.1 + (0.9/x)) }, function(x) { 1 / ( 0.3 + (0.7/x)) }. Comparing x_continuous vs x_log10 looks extremely different, when i expect something similar to what is produced by x_continuous. Is it possible to adjust this but keep ticks at same distance?.

Comment: Well yes, the way to get equidistant ticks on a linear (i.e. untransformed) scale is to use different breaks than you have now, like `seq(min, max, by = increment)`. With the numbers you've put into `xs`, wherein each value is 2x the previous one, you'd need a log-scale to have them appear equidistant. You can also cheese it by having the scale be linear and manually assigning labels that don't correspond to the values, but that's just confusing to everyone.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I think what helps to maintain the "original shape" is to also apply log10 on the y axis.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Plot
base <- ggplot(data.frame(x = xs), aes(x=as.factor(x)))
#Plot 2
base + theme_classic() +
  theme(
    legend.position = c(.95, .95),
    legend.justification = c("right", "top"),
    legend.box.just = "right",
    legend.margin = margin(6, 6, 6, 6)
  ) +
  stat_function(fun = fun.1, aes(colour = "fun.1"),geom = 'point',size=1) + 
  stat_function(fun = fun.1, aes(colour = "fun.1"),geom = 'line') + 
  stat_function(fun = fun.2, aes(colour = "fun.2"),geom='point',size=1) +
  stat_function(fun = fun.2, aes(colour = "fun.2"),geom = 'line') +
  stat_function(fun = fun.3, aes(colour = "fun.3"),geom = 'point',size=1) +
  stat_function(fun = fun.3, aes(colour = "fun.3"),geom = 'line') +
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Input",
                   breaks = xs) +
  scale_y_discrete(name = "Growth")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('red','blue','yellow'))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I looked into stat_function, although didn't try to use it twice for each function. The problem is there are more points than x ticks.

Comment: @fulem You could play around the size of points or using the approach from teunbrand, in any sense I hope the code give you any useful insight!