# How to change colour and add legend on Laplacian plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot a Laplacian density function with `ggplot2`. I wrote the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot() + 
  geom_function(fun = function(x) rmutil::dlaplace(x, m = 0, s = beta_true)) + 
  expand_limits(x=c(-10,10)) +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) rmutil::dlaplace(x, m = 0, s = beta_fake)) + 
  expand_limits(x=c(-10,10)) +
  xlab("Noise Range") +
  ylab("Probability")
```

This is what I got:

[image]

I want to give the two curves different colours, one pink another one purple. I also want to add a legend to indicate the colours of the corresponding curves.

I have also tried this:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot() + 
  geom_function(fun = function(x) rmutil::dlaplace(x, m = 0, s = beta_true), aes(color='beta_true')) + 
  expand_limits(x=c(-10,10)) +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) rmutil::dlaplace(x, m = 0, s = beta_fake), aes(color='beta_fake')) + 
  expand_limits(x=c(-10,10)) +
  xlab("Noise Range") +
  ylab("Probability") +
  scale_color_manual(name='Functions',values = c(beta_true='pink',beta_fake='purple'))
```

Comment: what is `beta_true` and `beta_fake` ? can you attach them ?

Comment: They are the scale parameters of the curves. Each curve has a unique scale parameter. They are just a value.

Comment: I will add a solution using function `sin` and `cos` , so you can apply for yours

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/q/65190074/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/47791400/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/54864805/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56560466/5325862, https://stackoverflow.com/q/61899270/5325862

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the package `rmutil` thus I couldn't draw your function; you can easily apply this method for yours;

```
library(ggplot2)
plot <- ggplot() + 
  geom_function(fun = function(x) sin(x),aes(color='Sinus')) + 
  expand_limits(x=c(-10,10)) +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) cos(x),aes(color='Cosinus')) + 
  expand_limits(x=c(-10,10)) +
  xlab("Noise Range") +
  ylab("Probability") +
  scale_color_manual(name='Functions',values = c(Sinus='pink',Cosinus='purple'))
```

**fields;**
[image]

Comment: I used your code excpet for lines 3, 5 and 9, where I have changed `Sinus` and `Cosinus`  to`beta_true` and `beta_fake`. So for example, my line 3 looks like this: `geom_function(fun = function(x) rmutil::dlaplace(x, m = 0, s = beta_true), aes(color='beta_true')) +`. But nothing appeared on my plot environment.

Comment: did you also change in `scale_color_manual` ?

Comment: Yes, I changed it to `scale_color_manual(name='Functions',values = c(beta_true='pink',beta_fake='purple'))`

Comment: probably there is a typo, can you attach what you tried at main question ?

Comment: there is already the same named objects in your R environment. update aes(color='beta_true2') etc. everywhere (I mean do it for beta_fake also and in scale_color_manual) . it will be fixed.